# How to add pagination in angular material table that bind to API response

Tags: angular, pagination, angular-material

I'm new to angular. In my project shown list of products and its work correctly.

My HTML code is below :

```html
<table mat-table [dataSource]="list_product" style="width: 20%;">
    <!-- id Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="id" style="width: 20%;">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef style="align-items: center;"> id </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let list_product"> {{list_product.id}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- description Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="description">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let list_product"> {{list_product.description}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
<mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
```

and my TypeScript code is -

```js
import { Component, OnInit,ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { analyzeAndValidateNgModules } from '@angular/compiler';
import { MatPaginator} from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material/table';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-basic',
    templateUrl: './basic.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./basic.component.scss']
})
export class BasicComponent implements OnInit {

    public list_product:any=[];
    displayedColumns: string[] = ['id', 'description'];
    @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;

    constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.get_data();
        this.list_product.paginator = this.paginator;
    }

    get_data(){
        this.http.get<any>("http://localhost:3000/listp").subscribe(
            res => this.list_product = res
        )
    }
}
```

Pagination does not work and all of list are shown. Pagination buttons does not work in html file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For client side pagination, the `MatTableDataSource` has pagination, sorting and filtering functionality built-in to it.

Follow the steps below -

1. Use `MatTableDataSource` type as the `dataSource` and initialize it with an empty array
2. Set the `data` property of `MatTableDataSource` once data is received
3. Get a reference of the table's `paginator` with `@ViewChild`
4. Implement `AfterViewInit` to set the `paginator` property of `MatTableDataSource` once the view is initialized

Your final component code should look something like -

```js
export class BasicComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
    
    public list_product = new MatTableDataSource<any>([]);  // <-- STEP (1)
    displayedColumns: string[] = ['id', 'description'];
    @ViewChild(MatPaginator) private paginator: MatPaginator;  // <-- STEP (3)

    constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.get_data();
    }

    get_data(){
        this.http.get<any>("http://localhost:3000/listp").subscribe(
            res => this.list_product.data = res  // <-- STEP (2)
        );
    }
    
    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        this.list_product.paginator = this.paginator;  // <-- STEP (4)
    }
}
```

You should explore [the documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples) for further details.

Comment: But for large data sets, the backend should paginate results right? else the UI will lag.

Comment: @chitgoks yes, as I mentioned, this is for client-side pagination.